# yeild inside section laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a master page (master_2) for user panel views and in there I have already had a master page (master_1) for main page content (etc header footer), anyway I have this for dynamic  , master_1 :

```
@extends('master_1') 
@section('website_title' , 'user panel - ' . @yeild('panel-title'))
```

and in a child view :

```
@extends('master_2')
@section('panel-title' , 'dashboard')
```

but it gives me an error :

```
The "yield" expression can only be used inside a function
```

I would appreciate any help and suggestions for better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically `@yield` works as a placeholder/slot for child content.

For example, this can be `master-1.blade.php`

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<!-- BEGIN: Head -->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    @yield('head')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="link/to/base-styles.css" />
    <script src="link/to/base-script.js"></script>
    @yield('pre-scripts')
    @yield('styles')
</head>

<body>
    @yield('header')
    @yield('main')
    @yield('footer')
    @yield('post-scripts')
</body>

</html>
```

And for `master-2.blade.php`:

```php
@extends('master-1')

@section('pre-scripts')
    Scripts here will load before the body
@endsection

@section('header')
    Add header markup here
@endsection

@section('main')
    You can add main body markup
    You can also yield more (sub) content
    @yield('sub-content')
    And if you @extend('master-2'), you can can slot html into those @yield-ed sections.
@endsection

@section('footer')
    Add footer markup here
@endsection

@section('post-scripts')
    Scripts here will load at the end of the page body
@endsection
```